# Import ESM into CJS code with Node 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

what is the correct way to import ESM into CJS with Node 10 without Babel ?

I'm currently doing this but i get a `Not supported` error, i think this is the Babel syntax but I can't seem to find the  `Node 10` syntax... (https://medium.com/@giltayar/native-es-modules-in-nodejs-status-and-future-directions-part-i-ee5ea3001f71)

```
//ESM Files (.mjs), Code executed in CJS, (.js), Node 10

//CJS code
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
for (const file of commandFiles) {
            let command =  await import(`./Commands/${file}`);
        }
//ESM code
class  MyClass {}
export default new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `--experimental-modules` flag missing in `node --experimental-modules app.js`.

I thought this was not needed in Node 10.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed you should run `node --experimental-modules app.mjs`.

Note that the naming convention is to keep the `.mjs` and run it directly (while `.js` is still for CommonJS).

Side notice: running `.mjs` with ES6 modules also works in the browser with `<script type=module src=path/to/app.mjs></script>`